# .append() does not work with table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to add a table to my website with jquery´s append function when the user hovers over the image $("#dot0003"). Dreamweaver already tells me that there is a syntax error but I don't understand where.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#dot0003").hover(
    function(){

        $("#tablespace").append('

        <table  id="table1" class="info0004" border="4">
        <tr>
        <td>roomnumber</td>
        <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>number of bathrooms</td>
        <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>number of beds</td>
        <td><img src="_index/_dots/dot.gif" width="20" height="20"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>')

})
})
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: your string 'a'+ 'b' not '  ... multil line''

Comment: JavaScript sadly doesn't care about semicolons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is what you're trying to do?  Meaning, when you hover over dot0003, it's going to keep trying to append this data.  See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8qrF/) here.

With that said, your issue is with your spaces.  See the fiddle above.  Either remove your spaces or build your string like:

```
var myContent = '<table  id="table1" class="info0004" border="4">'
myContent += '<tr>'
...
```

But this produces invalid HTML markup as your adding tables in your table like such:

```
<table>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <table>
    ...
```

I think you should use jQuery's `after` method instead of `append`.

Good luck.

Comment: I am good with removing the spaces. This way I am not having a problem with invalid HTML markup right?

Comment: No, this will fix the error, but not fix the invalid HTML.  Your invalid HTML is coming from using append rather than after -- append will add the table inside of closed table tag where after adds it after the close of the table.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your adding dynamic table syntax has a space so remove space then run
```

You can try to run using simple dynamic div

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dot0003").hover(
        function(){
            $("#tablespace").append('<div>ss</div>')})})
```

But when you will write syntax with space it will show error

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#dot0003").hover(
    function(){
        $("#tablespace").append('<div>ss
```

')})})

Try with this code after removing extra space

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#dot0003").hover(
    function(){

        $("#tablespace").append('<table id="table1" class="info0004" border="4">       <tr><td>roomnumber</td><td>200</td></tr>        <tr><td>number of bathrooms</td>       <td>2</td></tr><tr><td>number of beds</td>        <td><img src="_index/_dots/dot.gif" width="20" height="20"></td></tr></table>')

})
})
```